# XPath all descendents, even if nested - but not descendents of parent

Tags: c#, xpath

I am attempting to write XPath to work with some XML Nodes.

Sample of my XML is below (for Element name and nesting illustration).

```
<Forms> 
<Form> 
 <Control/> 
 <Control>   
    <Control></Control> 
 </Control> 
 <Control>
   <Form><!-- This is the nested one, I don't want the Control children from this-->
    <Control/>
   </Form>
 </Control>
</Form>
```

Is there a way to modify the XPath statement below - to include all Controls (even ones nested within eachother - under the "Form", but not from nested Form(see Form<2>)? This current XPath brings back "Controls" that are underneath nested "Form" nodes.

```
string xpath = @"/Forms/Form[@id='" + node.Attributes["id"].Value + "']//Control[@type='GroupItem' or @type='Detail' or @type='GroupHeader']";
```

I am basically trying to un-nest all Control tags, and wrap them with "Controls" tag, so I am using this Xpath in C# to reformat - but I don't want to pull Control out of a nested Form, I want to wrap their in Controls tag seperately.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Please, provide a complete example of the XML document (as small as possible) and the XPath expression that your code has generated that is actually being evaluated. Also provide information which exactly elements have been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 /Forms/Form[@id='blah']/descendant::Control[blah]
```

this uses the `descendant` axis on the Control lookup (the default is `child`)

Obviously replace the `blah` - they are just for brevity; the important thing in the above is `descendant::`

Comment: I missed something in the sample, there are Nested "Form" within other forms. I want all controls somewhere underneath a Form, but none of the one's under nested Form. So if Form has Form nested, I want all Control under Form, but not the controls under it's nested Form.

Comment: @user53885 - with that extra, it may be easier to do it in regular code... You might be able to do that in xpath, but that is very non-trivial

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0

```
//Control except //Form//Form//Control
```

or in XPath 1.0

```
//Control[not(ancestor::Form/ancestor::Form)]
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be `Control`s with just one `Form` ancestor:

```
//Control[count(ancestor::Form)=1]
```

**Edit**: Better

```
//Control[not(ancestor::Form[2])]
```